# Java: Perform Action Every X Seconds

Tags: java, user-interface, timer, draw

I've got a working Java program and I would like to draw an object on the display every X seconds.  What is the best way to do this?  I was thinking of using a `for` loop and some `sleep` statements, but I'm curious if there is an easier or more efficient way to go about this.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked out [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)?

Comment: using loop and sleep will freeze your application, so never do that.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to use a [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)

```
Timer timer = new Timer(X, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        // Update the variables you need...
        repaint();
    }
});

timer.setRepeats(true);
timer.setCoalesce(true);
timer.start();
```

You might also like to have a read through

- [The Event Dispatching Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)
- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

So you can understand why you should never use a `while (true) { Thread.sleep(X) }` call in `Swing` (inside the EDT)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Would it be possible to modify this so that after say, 5 minutes, I stop performing these actions all together?

Comment: It would be, you'd need to grab the start time and compare it with the current to figure out how long you've been running and call Timer.stop

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Would this calle to Timer.stop go inside of `actionPerformed` then?

Comment: Yep, so would the time comparisons

Answer (score 1):

[ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) might help here. The Javadoc shows example usage. Don't forget to call the `shutdown` method when you're finished.

Answer (score 0):

Using Thread, this will draw a rectangle on the screen every XMilSeconds. This will stop after 5 runs. Edit the xMilSeconds for slower runs, and j > 4 for how many runs before stoping. It does freeze though, that I can't fix.

```
int i = 0;
private long xMilSeconds = 300;
private boolean paint;
public boolean running = true;

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);
    if(paint)
    {
        for(;i < i+1;)
        {
             g.drawRect(i+49,i+49,i+299,i+99);   
             g.setColor(Color.RED);  
             g.fillRect(i+49,i+49,i+299,i+99); 
        }
        paint = false;
    }
}

public void run()
{
    while(running)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(xSeconds);
            paint = true;
            repaint();
            i++;
            j++;
            if(j > 4)
            {
                running = false;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```