# Not able to repaint in java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, repaint

I am not able to dynamically repaint() inside the Jframe.

```
public static BufferedImage createBufferedImage(BufferedImage image) 
{
    ColorModel cm = image.getColorModel();
    boolean premultiplied = cm.isAlphaPremultiplied();
    WritableRaster raster = image.copyData(image.getRaster());
    return new BufferedImage(cm, raster, premultiplied, null);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {


BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(old_width_i, old_height_i, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

img=createBufferedImage(img_white_screen);



JFrame frame=new JFrame();
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
frame.getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.WEST);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true); 
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

img.flush();
img=createBufferedImage(img_black_screen);
//  frame.removeAll();
//  frame.revalidate();
//  label.removeAll();
//  label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
//  frame.getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.WEST);

frame.repaint();
}
```

It basically, creates a screen with the first assignment to the "img" (i.e. img_white_screen) variable and does not change to the second assignment i.e. img_black_screen

Comment: use `label.setIcon(img)` after `img=createBufferedImage(img_black_screen);` . No need to repaint the JFrame.

Comment: What are you trying to repaint?

Comment: Sleeping on the EDT is a bad practice. It will lead to unpredictable behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

- [don't to use Thread.sleep(1000);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), this [code line lock Event Dispatch Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7944388/714968),
- no idea for why reason you need to pause code execution for one second, [use Swing Timer instead](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)
- for showing the Image in Java to use

  1. [XxxImage as Icon /IconImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) to [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)
  2. [`paintComponent() for JComponent or JPanel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html)
- don't paint `XxxImage` or `Icon / ImageIcon` directly to the `JFrame`, use `JPanel / JComponent` or `JLabel`

Comment: I will be trying the posted answers, but the reason why I was using Sleep is to make the feeling of rotation... Say, the image was two circle having two different reference lines...I use, sleep so that user get a illusion of a wheel rotating.. any better solutions... 
NOTE:I am manually priting all the pixels values on the screen

Comment: @JS_VIPER for a [basic example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593098/java-perform-action-every-x-seconds/12593132#12593132)